# phpmyadmin upgrade_column_info_4_3_0+.sql error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've installed phpMyAdmin 4.3.0. I try to configure phpmyadmin storage. In the manual is written:

- upgraded to MySQL 4.1.2 or newer, please use examples/upgrade_tables_mysql_4_1_2+.sql.
- upgraded to phpMyAdmin 4.3.0 or newer from 2.5.0 or newer (<= 4.2.x), please use examples/upgrade_column_info_4_3_0+.sql.

So I tried to import upgrade_column_info_4_3_0+.sql. But I got this error message:

```
ALTER TABLE `pma__column_info`
  ADD `input_transformation` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ADD `input_transformation_options` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '';


#1060 - Duplicate column name 'input_transformation'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It's because the columns already is added to the table pma__column_info

So just delete these last three lines in the upgrade_column_info_4_3_0+.sql file, and run it again:

ALTER TABLE `pma__column_info`
  ADD `input_transformation` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ADD `input_transformation_options` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '';